# How to count articles for every months in current year?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have list of months, and now i want to count articles for every month. 
I have this :

```
$data= Articles::get()
          ->groupBy(function($item) {
          return $item->created_at->month;
      });
```

And for now i get data for 11 and 12, but how can i do that so that i can have list of month names and next to them have number of articles for that month?

Comment: Are you looking for an advanced multi-language based solution with extra sugar, or how to write an lookup table with 12 entries? `$months = array('January', 'February', ...); $monthName = $months[$monthNum - 1];`

Comment: what is the output you are looking for can you share I can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($data as $key => $values) {
    $data[$key] = $values->count();
 }
    $data = $clicked->toArray();
```

This will give you the number of articules by Month and if you want the month name as the key then
group by

`$item->created_at->format('M')`

instead of your group by condition